# Knockout-sortable allowDrop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout-sortable

I have a list of droppable items for which I have a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.drag = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, "ko_drag_data", valueAccessor());
        var options = ko.utils.extend(ko.bindingHandlers.drag.options, allBindingsAccessor().dragOptions);
        $(element).draggable(options);
    },
    options: {}
};
```

I am initialising it with the options:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.drag.options = {
    connectToSortable: ".droppingZone",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stack: ".detail",
    cursor: "move",
    cancel: null
};
```

The draggable:

```
<div data-bind="drag: $data, dragOptions: { start: onDragStart, stop: onDragStop }, click: function (e) { $root.addField($data); }">
```

The sortable:

```
<div class="well droppingZone" data-bind="sortable: { data: fieldsHelper, allowDrop: $root.isListFull, options: { update: onUpdate } }">
```

I am dropping this elements into a sortable, using Knockout-sortable plugin.

I want the user to be allowed to drop until the list is full. That is why I am using `allowDrop: $root.isListFull` on the sortable binding as the documentation says.

The problem is that no matter what value `$root.isListFull` contains (true/false), I can still drop items in the sortable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce something in jsFiddle?  Here is a sample that you could fork: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UMQEn/. It uses the `draggable` binding that is built into the `sortable` library.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it in JsFiddle and it works there. Still does not work in the application though. I will try to include some more code into the fiddle...

Comment: I solved it. The problem seemed to be how the observable that I was sending to the `allowDrop:` was unwrapped. I was sending it already unwrapped (`!isFull()`), but sending it `isFull` worked.